# PHPWord - Is it possible to set min value for chart axis?

Tags: php, charts, phpword

I have this chart:

[image: chart]

As you see minimum value is 69.5 and there is big difference between two series, but I'd like to start Y axis from 0 to visually observe just a small difference, is it possible?

Didn't found anything about this feature in docs.

Answer (score 1):

i think to make your Y axis minimum value to '0' is you have to use `min` in `scales:` `y:` like code below.

```
scales: {
      y: {
        min: 0,
        ticks: {
          // forces step size to be 10 units
          stepSize: 10
        }
      }
    }
```

you can also use `stepSize` to make distance between the value. `stepSize: 10` mean starting from the value 0, then 10, etc.

Comment: Looks like this snippet is from chart.js but I'd like to find a solution in PHPWord php library